# What is "the result to the type expected by the invoker" in Java?

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I've been working with JSONPath recently. It's [`read()`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html#read-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate...-) function's parameters have the following description in the documentation:

```
Parameters:
json a json object
jsonPath the json path
filters filters to be applied to the filter place holders [?] in the path
**<T> expected return type**
```

My question is about the fourth parameter. It doesn't seem to be something I can pass in explicitly, since the read() method's signature is `(Object json, String jsonPath, Predicate... filters)`. On [JSONPath's GitHub page](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath), I'm told that:

> "When using JsonPath in java its important to know what type you
>   expect in your result. JsonPath will automatically try to cast the
>   result to the type expected by the invoker."

What exactly is mean by "the result type expected by the invoker"? How do I control this? Can I pass it in as an explicit parameter?

Comment: For example: `String expectedTypeIsString = read()`.

Comment: @m0skit0 If I do something like `ArrayList<String> realData = JsonPath.read(dataDumpFile, current.getPath());` it doesn't seem to work. If I'm reading in doubles for example `read()` returns an arraylist of doubles. Is there something special about arrays/arraylists or might this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` isn't the "fourth parameter", it's the [generic type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html). JsonPath is manipulating this language feature to allow them to define a single `read()` method that [returns different types at runtime](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when).

> When using JsonPath in java its important to know what type you expect in your result. JsonPath will **automatically try to cast the result** to the type expected by the invoker.

The "invoker" in this context is you, the caller. So in other words you specify the desired return type, and JsonPath will (hopefully) return an object of that type. Implementations of the [`MappingProvider`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/MappingProvider.html) interface define the supported transformations, but only certain types are configured.

To your specific question of "*Is there something special about arrays/arraylists*" I would hazard a guess that JsonPath doesn't return `ArrayList` objects, just `List` objects (notice they use `List` in the examples on GitHub), so it's likely all you need to do is change your return type to `List<String> realData`. In general try to specify the interface, rather than specific implementation, you expect.

That said, this runtime-type-guessing behavior is atypical (and not something generally encouraged in Java), so don't be surprised if it's confusing. You're essentially being asked to guess what types JsonPath can return to you.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't really do anything special. It just casts to the generic type T, which doesn't in fact do much since generics are erased. Java is what implicitly casts the returned value to the type of the variable to which the returned value is assigned

Comment: Yeah, it seems pretty unhelpful in my case. It seems like it just guesses what the type is then relies on Java to cast its guess to the type the invoker expects. So if I specify a `String` for example, I'm out of luck unless `(String) <JSONPath's guess>` works.

Comment: The only workaround I've found so far that works in my case (I'm not sure what type will be returned) is to ask for an Object. Then I have to use `instanceof` a whole bunch to check if JSONPath's guess lines up with the data types that typically get returned.

Comment: @JBNizet oof. I didn't want to assume it was that simplistic, but I suppose that would be the only option. It really doesn't seem like an improvement over just declaring the desired type explicitly, like Gson does.

Answer (score 1):

By "the result type expected by the invoker", it means the type of object you expect the read() function to return.  If you say `myVar = read(...)`, then the reference type of `myVar` (or some subclass of it) must be the type you're expectring to receive... well, you're the invoker, so that's the type expected by the invoker.

The `<T>` parameter is a type parameter using Java generics.  It's not at all like other parameters, so I don't like the documentation style that puts it in the method's parameter list.  You can't pass it in.  It doesn't even exist at run time.  It just helps the compiler sanity-check things.

Answer (score 1):

It does not represent a parameter you can pass to a method. It represents a generic parameter.

Signature of `read` is as follows:

```
public static <T> T read(Object json, String jsonPath, Predicate... filters)
```

It is a generic method. `T` is not its return type - it is a generic parameter. It is substituted by the actual type you need. So if you do something like:

```
Apple expectedApple = read(...);
```

The compiler will determine that you need a version of this method that returns Apples and use one.

This pattern is commonly used by parsers, so you don't need to cast the result yourself - instead the cast is done inside the library with the assumption that you know what you are doing. So ultimately, if you dig deeper you will find a line:

```
return (T) jsonObject;
```

Comment: That description ("the compiler will determine that you need a version of this method that returns Apples and use one") would be accurate for C++ templates, but not for Java generics.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Generics in Java are just a syntactic sugar - this method in reality returns Object, and casts to your desired class are added. I avoided driving in-depth into Java generics implementation to explain the concept in a simple way.